# Change variable conditionally on values of two variables

Tags: r

I have a variable called outcome, which values need to be replaced by NAs if var1 is higher than the variable time. This is how (part) of my dataset looks like:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 
475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 475, 413, 413, 413, 413, 
413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 413, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123), time = c("-1", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "baseline_survey", "doc", "pre_baseline", 
"screening", "3_m_tel", "3_m_survey", "3_m_nurse", "6_m_tel", 
"6_m_survey", "6_m_nurse", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"baseline_survey", "doc", "pre_baseline", "screening", "3_m_tel", 
"3_m_survey", "3_m_nurse", "6_m_tel", "6_m_survey", "6_m_nurse", 
"-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "baseline_survey", "doc", 
"pre_baseline", "screening", "3_m_tel", "3_m_survey", "3_m_nurse", 
"6_m_tel", "6_m_survey", "6_m_nurse", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "baseline_survey", "doc"), var1 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), outcome = c(7, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 7, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, 9, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 8, 8, 
12, 10, 8, 7, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So for example, for id 475, var1 is 3, so the outcome variable should be replaced by NAs when the time variable is higher than 3 (timepoints 4 and 5). For id 413, the outcome variable should be replaced by NAs for all time points higher than 2, and so on…

I tried with mutate (and case_when) but I failed miserably…

```
df %>%
  mutate(outcome1= ifelse((var1 > time) , NA outcome))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `NA` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to convert the 'time' to `integer` class as it is `character`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(outcome1= ifelse((var1 > as.integer(time)) , NA,  outcome))
```

Comment: You are right! Very good to know this! :)